# Angularjs ng-repeat for array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have array that creates via this script:

```
    $scope.bindModel = function(data) {
        $scope.model = data;
        $scope.projects = projectNames();
        $scope.$apply($timeout($scope.bindModel(data)));
    };

    /* Function that enumerates the names of the project in the list of model's object*/
    var projectNames = function () {
        var array = [];
        // SOME CODE . . .
        return array;
    };
```

And it's creates array like this:

```
$scope.projects = ["first project", "second project", "third project"];
```

And when I try to show it on page via ng-repeat="project in projects", nothing not shows, but in debug console massive have values. Where did I go wrong?
I use this in select:

```
<select class="chzn-border" style="width:98%">
     <option disabled selected style='display:none;'>Choose a project...</option>
     <option ng-repeat="project in projects" value="{{project}}">{{project}}</option>
</select>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HUSTLIN/ovoxn7c3/4/)

Comment: Do you call `$scope.bindModel` anywhere?

Comment: Yeah, it's calls on page load, $scope.model in ng-repeat works normally, but $scope.projects not

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or plunker. That will help us to see the code completely and help you.

Comment: Does projectNames() return a promise by any chance?  Have you tried calling $scope.$apply afterwards?

Comment: It will be more help if you create a fiddle/plunker. I tried your code and it works. $scope.projects = ["first project", "second project", "third project"]; and the html code totally works. Please check if your html code is within scope of the controller where you are setting the $scope.projects.

Comment: @ashfaq.p, I can't add full code, but i create something like original
http://jsfiddle.net/HUSTLIN/ovoxn7c3/

Comment: @HUSTLIN you have not added angular library.

Comment: @James Brierly, I don't tried $scope.$apply, because my js knowledge is bad, I don't what this and when I need to use it, and where :)

Comment: @ashfaq.p, sorry, already fixed

Comment: You can accept the answer as it helped you. This will help other users looking at your answer.

Comment: You should at least update the original question with your fix.  What was the issue?

Comment: You do not need to do $scope.$apply inside $timeout because $timeout itself wraps the code inside $scope.$apply. so just $timeout is fine.

Comment: why are you not using ngOptions??

Comment: updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ovoxn7c3/8/. Its woking

Comment: @ashfaq.p, yea it works, but only on jsfiddle ;)

Comment: Then make a fiddle of your full code and ill help you.

Answer (score 0):

According to me angular is unaware of the changes made to $scope.Projects. So you should call `$scope.bindModel` in apply.
Try using timeout which will wrap your code in $scope.$apply.

```
$timeout($scope.bindModel(data));
```

Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Yea, this fix a part of problem, now with this my scope see projects, but ng-repeat not work no matter (

Comment: I think $timeout is not needed, because without timeout it works same, and scope see projects

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a hint from where you can get idea to solve your ng-repeat problem:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="submit" ng-click="projectNames()" value="submit"></input>
    <select class="chzn-border" style="width:98%">
     <option disabled selected style='display:none;'>Choose a project...</option>
     <option ng-repeat="project in projects" value="{{project}}">{{project}}</option>
</select>
```

Angular JS:

```
function MyController($scope) {
  // $scope.bindModel = function(data) {
        //$scope.model = data;
        //$scope.projects = projectNames();
    //alert($scope.projects);
    //};

    $scope.projects = [];
    $scope.projectNames = function () {
        $scope.projects.push(" a is a project.");
        $scope.projects.push(" b is a project.");
        $scope.projects.push(" c is a project.");
    };

}
```

Here i have used a button that is helping to load the array and then in html ng-repeat is applied on array to show the data. You can load array on load like you want.

Comment: This unnecessarily adds one more method on scope when a local variable could have done the job.